# Flawless way of preventing element from being affected by external css

Tags: css, inheritance

I'm doing a script that will be implemented in multiple pages and I'm trying to prevent the elements it generates from being styled by the pages css. Some people have the great idea of writing css like this:

```
body>*{min-height:200px;}
```

So I found this new css property:

```
.elem{ all: initial }
```

And it seems to work quite well but I've already experienced some problems and I bet there may be many that I don't know about.
For example, for internet explorer (even ie11!!!) to reset min-height, you can't use initial, you must use 0! Therefore, `all:initial`, doesn't override min-height...

Do you know of a better way to do this or at least a list of properties I should take care of individually??

**EDIT: To better explain what I want. I will do this in JS (I mentioned before it is a script), and I'm not only interested in solutions. I'd like to know why that solution works and why is better than the one I offer. Also, I'm aware of performance, so I'd rather like to use the minimun amount of rules, if posible: I'd like to know for example, which are the most dangerous ones.**

Comment: My best bet would be to include the elements using an iframe like most other services... Just check the facebook like button on webpages. It might not suit your project tough, but I'd definitely have a look in this direction as not only CSS can become problematic.

Comment: @Vandervals do you control the other pages or is this something that you'll be distributing to places where the style is unknown?

Comment: without control over the other pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now we don't have unified CSS effects on all major browsers! But we can still create a class which will reset most of all CSS properties to their initial values! Look at the below code:

```
.reset-this {
    animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-name : none;
    animation-play-state : running;
    animation-timing-function : ease;
    backface-visibility : visible;
    background : 0;
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-clip : border-box;
    background-color : transparent;
    background-image : none;
    background-origin : padding-box;
    background-position : 0 0;
    background-position-x : 0;
    background-position-y : 0;
    background-repeat : repeat;
    background-size : auto auto;
    border : 0;
    border-style : none;
    border-width : medium;
    border-color : inherit;
    border-bottom : 0;
    border-bottom-color : inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-style : none;
    border-bottom-width : medium;
    border-collapse : separate;
    border-image : none;
    border-left : 0;
    border-left-color : inherit;
    border-left-style : none;
    border-left-width : medium;
    border-radius : 0;
    border-right : 0;
    border-right-color : inherit;
    border-right-style : none;
    border-right-width : medium;
    border-spacing : 0;
    border-top : 0;
    border-top-color : inherit;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border-top-style : none;
    border-top-width : medium;
    bottom : auto;
    box-shadow : none;
    box-sizing : content-box;
    caption-side : top;
    clear : none;
    clip : auto;
    color : inherit;
    columns : auto;
    column-count : auto;
    column-fill : balance;
    column-gap : normal;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor;
    column-rule-color : currentColor;
    column-rule-style : none;
    column-rule-width : none;
    column-span : 1;
    column-width : auto;
    content : normal;
    counter-increment : none;
    counter-reset : none;
    cursor : auto;
    direction : ltr;
    display : inline;
    empty-cells : show;
    float : none;
    font : normal;
    font-family : inherit;
    font-size : medium;
    font-style : normal;
    font-variant : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    height : auto;
    hyphens : none;
    left : auto;
    letter-spacing : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    list-style : none;
    list-style-image : none;
    list-style-position : outside;
    list-style-type : disc;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    max-height : none;
    max-width : none;
    min-height : 0;
    min-width : 0;
    opacity : 1;
    orphans : 0;
    outline : 0;
    outline-color : invert;
    outline-style : none;
    outline-width : medium;
    overflow : visible;
    overflow-x : visible;
    overflow-y : visible;
    padding : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    padding-left : 0;
    padding-right : 0;
    padding-top : 0;
    page-break-after : auto;
    page-break-before : auto;
    page-break-inside : auto;
    perspective : none;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
    position : static;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
    right : auto;
    tab-size : 8;
    table-layout : auto;
    text-align : inherit;
    text-align-last : auto;
    text-decoration : none;
    text-decoration-color : inherit;
    text-decoration-line : none;
    text-decoration-style : solid;
    text-indent : 0;
    text-shadow : none;
    text-transform : none;
    top : auto;
    transform : none;
    transform-style : flat;
    transition : none;
    transition-delay : 0s;
    transition-duration : 0s;
    transition-property : none;
    transition-timing-function : ease;
    unicode-bidi : normal;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    visibility : visible;
    white-space : normal;
    widows : 0;
    width : auto;
    word-spacing : normal;
    z-index : auto;
}
```

Check out these links for more details:

[Source of Properties](https://github.com/peteboere/css-crush/blob/master/misc/initial-values.ini) | [MDN Initial Value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm doing a script that will be implemented in multiple pages and I'm trying to prevent the elements it generates from being styled by the pages css.

Not the most common thing to do in CSS, it's usually the other way round, so the solutions won't be common. Unless you want to generate inline rules in JavaScript, but I'll stay with CSS-only solutions.

One thing is to use a class and define a rule for each tag with that class (in order to make it more specific) - it's like a tag-specific reset class now, so say the class is called `untouched`:

```
a.untouched
div.untouched
.someOther.untouched
...etc
```

Now, I don't know how well structured your original CSS is - the better it's structured, the less of those `untouched` elements you'd have.

Even that might not be enough in some cases where the original rules have a higher specificity, and in order to overcome that (and not having to manually whitelist all the instance variations), I'm afraid you'd have to use the notorious `!important` rule for all those reset rules, like so:

```
a.untouched {color: black !important; font-size: 16px !important}
```

It looks ugly and it's definitely not the best practice, but it probably the easiest/most common sense solution in your case.

And here's a great tool for calculating selector specificity: http://specificity.keegan.st/

---

Here's a simple example with a few paragraph variations:

```css
p {color: #999; font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 2px;}
p.red {color: red}
p.big {font-size: 20px}
p#superRed {color: red; text-shadow: 0 0 4px red;}
p > span {color: blue}

p.untouched, p.untouched > span {color: green !important; font-size: 12px !important; text-shadow: none !important;}
```

```html
Originals: 

<p>Test</p>
<p class="red">Test</p>
<p class="big">Test</p>
<p class="big red">Test</p>
<p id="superRed">Test</p>
<p><span>Test</span></p>

<br><br>
Untouched: 

<p class="untouched">Test</p>
<p class="untouched red">Test</p>
<p class="untouched big">Test</p>
<p class="untouched big red">Test</p>
<p class="untouched" id="superRed">Test</p>
<p class="untouched"><span>Test</span></p>
```

---

JS version of the example above:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#m *');

var style = {
  'color': 'green',
  'font-size': '12px',
  'text-shadow': 'none'
}

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  console.log(els[i], els[i].style['color']);
  for(var s in style) {    
    els[i].style[s] = style[s];
  }
}
```

```css
p {color: #999; font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 2px;}
p.red {color: red}
p.big {font-size: 20px}
p#superRed {color: red; text-shadow: 0 0 4px red;}
p > span {color: blue}
```

```html
Originals:

<p>Test</p>
<p class="red">Test</p>
<p class="big">Test</p>
<p class="big red">Test</p>
<p id="superRed">Test</p>
<p><span>Test</span>
</p>
<br><br>
New ones:

<div id="m">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p class="red">Test</p>
  <p class="big">Test</p>
  <p class="big red">Test</p>
  <p id="superRed">Test</p>
  <p><span>Test</span></p>
<div>
```

Comment: Actually I must do it with JS, which will be the same only that without using classes. Although I wouldn't like to specify every rule, only the most dangerous ones!

Comment: That actually makes your life much easier - create a JS object with a set of reset rules (you can have separate rules for each tag/element type), select all the problematic elements and just apply the JS object on their style.

Answer (score 2):

What about using [Cleanslate](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate) ?

Wrap your generated elements with a container that has the class "cleanslate" and style the elements within that container with !important rules. 
More information can be found on the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Your only working best bet is to re-define styles in Javascript program by hand for all elements your program creates. For example, in jQuery:

```
$('.my-own-elem').css('attr', 'value');
```

That is, you create an element and immediately style it as you want. To prevent FOUC, you can create a raw DOM element, style it, and attach it after it was completely prepared.

Realistically, overrides of styles from Javascript takes maximal precedence in all browsers. It's quite a lot of work, however, to style via Javascript, and it'll be even more work to make resulting code maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

If you style an element inline-ly, it won't be affected by external css unless you use [style] attribute to override the inline style.

Example:

```
<p style="background: red;">Paragraph</p>
```

The only way to override that style in an external css file will be like this:

```
p[style] {background: black !important;}
```

So the element won't be affected by external css unless you want to.